# Kotlin withTimeout coroutine cancellation

Tags: android, kotlin, gps, coroutine

I'm trying for the first time the coroutine function `withTimeout`. I'm trying to fetch the current location from the device GPS in Android, and add a timeout in case no location is available. I'm not controlling the process of fetching a location so I cannot make it cancellable easily.

Update: I ended up with a custom timeout logic as the android native api is not cancellable:

```
suspend fun LocationManager.listenLocationUpdate(): Location? = 
   withTimeoutOrNull(TIMEOUT) {
       locationManager.listenLocationUpdate("gps")
   }

  private suspend fun LocationManager.listenLocationUpdate(provider: String) =
        suspendCoroutine<Location?> { continuation ->
            requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0f, object: TimeoutLocationListener{
                override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
                    continuation.resume(location)
                    this@listenLocationUpdate.removeUpdates(this)
                }
            })
        }
```

So the process of requesting a location belongs to the sdk and I cannot make it cancellale easily. Any suggestion?

Comment: What is `LocationManager`? I don't see a `requestLocation()` function in official Android docs for `LocationManager` class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager . Is this some 3rd party lib?

Comment: This is just an example piece of code to expose the scenario.

Comment: In generic case I believe it is not possible to cancel the code that is in a blocked state and does not cooperate. I imagine it should be technically possible to at least resume the coroutine waiting on `withTimeoutOrNull()`, but it would leak the coroutine blocked inside.

Comment: As @broot said, for `withTimeout[OrNull]` to work, you need a cooperative cancellable coroutine. If the function you call is blocking, it will not work as expected. I don't think the calling coroutine would even be able to resume at all, let alone stop the processing of the blocking method. You have to have a cancellable API for it to work. With Android's LocationManager, it seems you should be able to turn this listener-based API into a cancellable `Flow`-based API which removes the listener upon cancellation (using `callbackFlow`)

Comment: It would help to have the actual code you're calling here, because whether this works or not is entirely dependent on what you call.

Comment: @Joffrey I've updated the code, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `withTimeout[OrNull]` to work, you need a cooperative cancellable coroutine. If the function you call is blocking, it will not work as expected. The calling coroutine will not even resume at all, let alone stop the processing of the blocking method. You can check [this playground code](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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) to confirm this.

You have to have a cancellable API in the first place if you want to build coroutine-based APIs that are cancellable. It's hard to answer your question without knowing the exact function you're calling, though.

With Android's `LocationManager`, you can for instance wrap [getCurrentLocation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager#getCurrentLocation(java.lang.String,%20android.os.CancellationSignal,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20java.util.function.Consumer%3Candroid.location.Location%3E)) into a cancellable suspending function (this function is only available in API level 30+):

```kotlin
@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R)
@RequiresPermission(anyOf = [permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION])
suspend fun LocationManager.getCurrentLocation(provider: String, executor: Executor): Location? = suspendCancellableCoroutine { cont ->
    val signal = CancellationSignal()

    getCurrentLocation(provider, signal, executor) { location: Location? ->
        cont.resume(location)
    }

    cont.invokeOnCancellation {
        signal.cancel()
    }
}
```

Otherwise you could also use `callbackFlow` to turn the listener-based API into a cancellable Flow-based API which unsubscribes upon cancellation (by removing the listener):

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalCoroutinesApi::class)
@RequiresPermission(anyOf = [permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION])
fun LocationManager.locationUpdates(provider: String, minTimeMs: Long, minDistance: Float = 0f): Flow<Location> =
    callbackFlow {
        val listener = LocationListener { location -> sendBlocking(location) }
        requestLocationUpdates(provider, minTimeMs, minDistance, listener)

        awaitClose {
            removeUpdates(listener)
        }
    }
```

You can use `first()` on the returned flow if you just want one update, and this will automatically support cancellation:

```kotlin
suspend fun LocationManager.listenLocationUpdate(): Location? = 
   withTimeoutOrNull(TIMEOUT) {
       locationManager.locationUpdates("gps", 1000).first()
   }
```

If you use `numUpdates = 1` in your location request, you should also be able to wrap the listener-based API into a single-shot suspending function too. Cancellation here could be done by just removing the listener.

Comment: I've updated the code with my current solution. I do not need a flow as response, I just need a single Location, so I've used suspendCoroutine to convert the callback based api into a coroutine. But I still don't like this solution.

Comment: @VictorManuelPinedaMurcia the code you updated is not quite correct, as you may get exceptions because `requestLocationUpdates` will try to resume the continuation multiple times. Also, you should use `suspendCancellableCoroutine` so you can actually support cancellation.

Comment: @VictorManuelPinedaMurcia I updated the answer to show how to use the flow API even for a single shot query (with built-in cancellation).